# Editing Labels in Legend using ArcPy in PyCharm

Tags: arcpy, labeling, legend, pycharm

I have created this map in PyCharm with ArcPy software, and was wondering if there is a code I can use to remove the 'High' and 'Low' labels and just show the numeric values in the legend. Using ArcMap version 10.7.1.

Here is a sample of the code I've used to edit items in the legend:

```
#Using Style Manager to edit the appearance of the Legend 
#edit study area in legend
mxd1 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\\Users\\Windows\\Desktop\\test\\map\\map_test.mxd")
df1 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd1, "Layers")[0]
lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd1, "Noise (dBA)", df1)[0]
styleItem = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems("C:\\Users\\Windows\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.7\\ArcMap\\Windows.style", "Legend Items", "Noise (dBA)")[0]
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd1, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
legend.updateItem(lyr1, styleItem)
mxd1.save()
```

I have also used the 'apply symbology from layer' tool, but this did not effect or change the labels.

[image]

Comment: You've created a map in Pycharm with which software? QGIS, Matplotlib, Vega, Altair,... Do you have an excerpt of code (anonymized if sensitive data) you can share so we can help? To make the comparison, it's like if you asked us to fix a plane without giving us the model and explaining how it has been broken and we have to guess from these clues. Not possible even with the best intentions. Thanks for any additional inputs

Comment: My apologies! I am new to coding and this platform, I appreciate you letting me know as this community has been so helpful thus far, I have edited my question.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to tell us the ArcMap / ArcGIS pro version you are using https://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/getinstallinfo.htm using "GetInstallInfo example 2" recipe? PS: can't help directly this answer as I don't use ESRI products but can help you refine your question to get adequate answer.

Comment: Just updated it! Thank you!